# Python 3.3 HTTPConnection endheaders and send data

Tags: python, send, httpconnection

Under `Python 3.3/Lib/urllib/request.py`, in class `AbstractHTTPHandler(BaseHandler)`, at line **1252**

> h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)

Under `Python 3.3/Lib/http/client.py` in class `HTTPConnection`, in the following lines:

**Line 1047**

> def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):

**Line 1068**

> def _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers):

**Line 1087**

> self.endheaders(body)

Above the body and req.data would correspond to the same string or other data, when `urllib.request.urlopen(req, data)` calls `request(method, url, body=None, headers={})` in `http.client.HTTPConnection`.

Does this mean that the following two are the same? (They don't seem to be the same in the doc)

1. `HTTPConnection.endheaders(data)`
2. `HTTPConnection.endheaders()`, `HTTPConnection.send(data)`

I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endheaders` uses `send` internally (indirectly). The difference might be in performance. If `data` is a bytes object then `.endheaders(data)` tries to send headers and data together. See [the comment in `_send_output()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8b793a946acb/Lib/http/client.py#l887):

```
896         # If msg and message_body are sent in a single send() call,
897         # it will avoid performance problems caused by the interaction
898         # between delayed ack and the Nagle algorithm.
```

Comment: ah.. Thanks so much! That was very timely and helpful.